# iOS - How to scroll horizontally in sprite kit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scroll, sprite-kit

I have a SKSpriteNode that is too big for the view and I am looking for a simple way in Sprite Kit to scroll horizontally to be able to see it completely.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: You could use a scroll view. It would create some challenges to do in SpriteKit, but there are answers on SO that can help with that...

Answer (score 3):

You could try using an `SKCameraNode` and respond to a pan gesture like so:

```
// GameScene.swift
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.camera = SKCameraNode()

    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePanFrom(recognizer:)))
    panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
}

func handlePanFrom(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state != .changed {
        return
    }

    // Get touch delta
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: recognizer.view!)

    // Move camera
    self.camera?.position.x -= translation.x
    self.camera?.position.y += translation.y

    // Reset
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: recognizer.view)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get neat scroll-view-like UX is ... to use a Scroll View. Nest one in your SKSceneView:

```
Scene View
|-Scroll View
```

Then you need to set up a `contentSize` of the Scroll View according to the scene width and viewport width. Here you should make some corresponding calculations depending on the `scaleMode` of the scene and other specific features of your layout.

There are very good lessons from Raywenderlich on this topic:
[Scroll View School Part 13: Sprite Kit Integration](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2388-video-tutorial-scroll-view-school-part-13-sprite-kit-integration)
[Scroll View School Part 14: Sprite Kit Level Selector](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2386-video-tutorial-scroll-view-school-part-14-sprite-kit-level-selector)
The lessons are good because they are very detailed. They will tell you how to convert coordinates correctly. However, some things are not ideal there: for example you don't need to add a content view to the scroll view, setting the `contentSize` will be enough. Also, I recommend to use `SKCameraNode` instead of putting everything in a root "world" node.

After this you must listen to the Scroll View's `delegate`:

```
// Example from one of my games
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let scrollWidth = scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.width
    guard scrollWidth > 0.01 else { return }
    let relativePosX = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollWidth

    // Feed relative position to the scene.
    // `setCameraRelativePosition` will convert it into the absolute camera
    // coordinates in the scene coordinate space
    gameScene.setCameraRelativePosition(relativePosX)
}
```

... and update your tilemap or camera position as appropriate.

`UIPanGestureRecognizer` will never give your deceleration and bouncing like a native Scroll View.